# Ajax ruby on rails not render js.erb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

my ploblem

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $("select#product_subcategory_id").change(function(){
        var id_value_string = $(this).val();
        if (id_value_string == "") {  
        }
        else{
          $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url: /admin_property_update/ + id_value_string,
            dataType : 'script'
          });
        }
        return false;  
      });
    </script>
```

this js code in view. In controller I have

```
def admin_property_update
    subcategory = Subcategory.find(params[:id])
    @properties = subcategory.properties 
end
```

And I have admin_property_update.js.erb

```
$('#property').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("admin/products/property")) %>');
```

_property.html.erb:

```
<% @properties.each do |property|%>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label"><%= property.title%></label>
          <div class="col-lg-9">
            <% if property.value_property_product == nil%>
              <%= text_field_tag "product[value_property_products][#{property.id}]", nil, class: "form-control" %>
            <% else%>
              <%= text_field_tag "product[value_property_products][#{property.id}]", property.value_property_product.value, class: "form-control" %>
            <%end%>
          </div>
        </div>
      <%end%>
```

And new.html.erb

```
<% unless @properties.empty?%>        
  <div id="property">
    <%= render("admin/products/property")%>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

In terminal I see, what request comes and processed in controller, but on page, NOT render _property.html.erb. What is wrong? 
THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this

```
$('#property').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "admin/products/property") %>');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help :(

Comment: now, please check element with `property` id exist on dom. because you have applied check outside of div.if you do not have properties then div will not create on page.